# Alfresco 3.4.e Share : Big PDF file preview doesn't work

Tags: pdf, encoding, alfresco, pdf2swf

I have an issue with my Alfresco 3.4.e Share application. When you upload a file, for instance a PDF file, that has a significant size (in this case 10MB), the "preview file via browser" option doesn't work. The window opens, the document is being processed, then it crashes.
When you try to preview a small file like a 1mb file, you don't get any problem.

I've made researches about this issue and apparently, you can modify the "content transformation limitations". Here is a link to the documentation I've refered to :

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Transformation_Limits

To sum up, all you have to do by setting properties in the "content-services-context.xml" file and the "thumbnail-services-context.xml".
Here are the properties you have to set :

- timeoutMs
- readLimitTimeMs
- maxSourceSizeKBytes
- readLimitKBytes
- pageLimit
- maxPages

However, none of these properties are existing for example in the class `"org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.magick.ImageTransformationOptions"` or in the class 
"org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.TextToPdfContentTransformer".
I've got an error when those properties are setted saying that they aren't writable and I've looked at the source and they simply don't existing.

I have another theory, in which the file is to complexe for being converted (more than 100 pages, lots of images and styling...).
Here is the error log that is written after the document conversion and preview attempts :

```
ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: 07060002 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 07060007 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/thumbnail/thumbnail.get.js': 07060006 Content conversion failed:
   reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2012/8/6/10/57/cd79670a-6210-4ce6-9af6-563d224c278f.bin, mimetype=application/pdf, size=20578433, encoding=utf-8, locale=fr_FR]
   writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2012/8/6/15/9/d44c8099-06ac-4c8f-8021-edb8f48c838b.bin, mimetype=application/x-shockwave-flash, size=0, encoding=UTF-8, locale=fr]
   options: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TransformationOptions@4b10fe3f
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 07060002 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 07060007 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/thumbnail/thumbnail.get.js': 07060006 Content conversion failed:
   reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2012/8/6/10/57/cd79670a-6210-4ce6-9af6-563d224c278f.bin, mimetype=application/pdf, size=20578433, encoding=utf-8, locale=fr_FR]
   writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2012/8/6/15/9/d44c8099-06ac-4c8f-8021-edb8f48c838b.bin, mimetype=application/x-shockwave-flash, size=0, encoding=UTF-8, locale=fr]
   options: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TransformationOptions@4b10fe3f
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:758)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.content.StreamContent.execute(StreamContent.java:202)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$2.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:383)
        at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:381)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:436)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:466)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:304)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:333)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:189)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:118)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:58)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException: 07060007 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/thumbnail/thumbnail.get.js': 07060006 Content conversion failed:
   reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2012/8/6/10/57/cd79670a-6210-4ce6-9af6-563d224c278f.bin, mimetype=application/pdf, size=20578433, encoding=utf-8, locale=fr_FR]
   writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2012/8/6/15/9/d44c8099-06ac-4c8f-8021-edb8f48c838b.bin, mimetype=application/x-shockwave-flash, size=0, encoding=UTF-8, locale=fr]
   options: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TransformationOptions@4b10fe3f
        at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:194)
        at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:282)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102)
        at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:981)
        at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.content.StreamContent.execute(StreamContent.java:148)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentIOException: 07060006 Content conversion failed:
   reader: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2012/8/6/10/57/cd79670a-6210-4ce6-9af6-563d224c278f.bin, mimetype=application/pdf, size=20578433, encoding=utf-8, locale=fr_FR]
   writer: ContentAccessor[ contentUrl=store://2012/8/6/15/9/d44c8099-06ac-4c8f-8021-edb8f48c838b.bin, mimetype=application/x-shockwave-flash, size=0, encoding=UTF-8, locale=fr]
   options: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.TransformationOptions@4b10fe3f
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.AbstractContentTransformer2.transform(AbstractContentTransformer2.java:177)
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.ContentServiceImpl.transform(ContentServiceImpl.java:555)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.alfresco.repo.model.ml.MLContentInterceptor.invoke(MLContentInterceptor.java:125)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:44)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.proceed(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:160)
        at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:137)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:107)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy42.transform(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.executer.AbstractTransformationRenderingEngine.render(AbstractTransformationRenderingEngine.java:71)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.executer.AbstractRenderingEngine.executeRenditionImpl(AbstractRenderingEngine.java:497)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.executer.AbstractRenderingEngine$2.doWork(AbstractRenderingEngine.java:429)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.executer.AbstractRenderingEngine$2.doWork(AbstractRenderingEngine.java:410)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:508)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.executer.AbstractRenderingEngine.executeImpl(AbstractRenderingEngine.java:409)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.executer.AbstractRenderingEngine.executeImpl(AbstractRenderingEngine.java:373)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.ActionExecuterAbstractBase.execute(ActionExecuterAbstractBase.java:133)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.directActionExecution(ActionServiceImpl.java:749)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeActionImpl(ActionServiceImpl.java:675)
        at org.alfresco.repo.action.ActionServiceImpl.executeAction(ActionServiceImpl.java:540)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.invoke(AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:44)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.proceedWithAudit(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:217)
        at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.proceed(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:184)
        at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:137)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:107)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy34.executeAction(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionServiceImpl.executeRenditionAction(RenditionServiceImpl.java:233)
        at org.alfresco.repo.rendition.RenditionServiceImpl.render(RenditionServiceImpl.java:182)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailServiceImpl.createThumbnailNode(ThumbnailServiceImpl.java:449)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailServiceImpl.access$000(ThumbnailServiceImpl.java:55)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailServiceImpl$1.doWork(ThumbnailServiceImpl.java:146)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailServiceImpl$1.doWork(ThumbnailServiceImpl.java:143)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:508)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailServiceImpl.createThumbnail(ThumbnailServiceImpl.java:141)
        at org.alfresco.repo.thumbnail.ThumbnailServiceImpl.createThumbnail(ThumbnailServiceImpl.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.invoke(AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:44)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.proceed(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:178)
        at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:137)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:107)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy111.createThumbnail(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptNode.createThumbnail(ScriptNode.java:2410)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:155)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:243)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:76)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12._c1(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/thumbnail/thumbnail.get.js:61)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12.call(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/thumbnail/thumbnail.get.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:108)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12._c0(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/thumbnail/thumbnail.get.js:101)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12.call(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/thumbnail/thumbnail.get.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12.call(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/thumbnail/thumbnail.get.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c12.exec(file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/thumbnail/thumbnail.get.js)
        at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:472)
        at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:190)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentIOException: 07060005 Transformation failed - status indicates an error:
Execution result:
   os:         Windows Server 2008 R2
   command:    [C:/Alfresco/swftools/pdf2swf.exe, -T, 9, -s, poly2bitmap,subpixels=72, C:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker_source_1313428204114423249.pdf, -o, C:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker_target_920011681678277152.swf]
   succeeded:  false
   exit code:  1
   out:        NOTICE  processing PDF page 1 (595x841:0:0) (move:0:0)
NOTICE  File contains pbm pictures
NOTICE  File contains jpeg pictures
NOTICE  processing PDF page 2 (595x841:0:0) (move:0:0)
NOTICE  processing PDF page 3 (595x841:0:0) (move:0:0)
NOTICE
   err:
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker.transform(RuntimeExecutableContentTransformerWorker.java:272)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:71)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy40.transform(Unknown Source)
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.ProxyContentTransformer.transformInternal(ProxyContentTransformer.java:68)
        at org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.AbstractContentTransformer2.transform(AbstractContentTransformer2.java:161)
        ... 125 more
```

If you look at the log, the problem may be linked to `pdf2swf` which crashes due to high bytes characters or specials characters.

So, if any of you have an idea...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: Please do not use 3.4.e Community. The stable 3.4 Community release is 3.4.d. 3.4.e was meant as a "preview" release for Activiti integration.

Answer (score 2):

There should not be any transformation limits on place on your out-of-the-box install, even if the limits are implemented in your version. So unless you have specifically configured limits, it's unlikely that this is likely to be the cause of your problem.

What's more likely is that `pdf2swf` is simply unable to process the file you uploaded. This seems consistent with the stack trace that you posted from your log, but note that Alfresco will truncate the error stream. If you really want to see the full error then take the command it gives you and run it interactively at a command prompt.

You don't mention what version of SWFTools you have installed, but this would be a good place to start. You could try a more recent version or SVN snapshot, and see if this helps.

Lastly you can also change the command line parameters that are passed to `pdf2swf`, although you would need to do a bit of research in order to understand what parameters work best for the type of content you are going to be uploading.

The following default settings are set in the file `alfresco/subsystems/thirdparty/default/swf-transform.properties` inside the Alfresco webapp, but you can override them in your custom `alfresco-global.properties` file.

```
# This option on pdf2swf improves the transformation of graphics-heavy pdfs. See ALF-3580.
# poly2bitmap improves the chances of successful transformation. On its own it reduces
# the resolution of embedded images. subpixels sets the dpi for embedded images.
# zoom introduced and -s added before each option (ALF-9417).
swf.encoder.params=-s zoom=72 -s ppmsubpixels=1 -s poly2bitmap=1 -s bitmapfonts=1
```

The issues (on http://issues.alfresco.com) referenced in the comments may also be of interest.

Comment: Thanks, I've modified the configuration as you suggest and it works fine. I've responded to this post with my current configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you look back at the first lines of the wiki, you will notice that property limit applies to Enterprise version 3.4.8 or 4. I am not sure that it applies to version 3.4.d. But, in any case, that's besides the point. Those limits were created in the recent versions to avoid the kind of error that you got from pdf2swf.exe, and present a static image as a preview, which might not be as pretty as the regular Flash preview, but at least it will get you a preview. That feature might not be available in 3.4d, albeit it probably is available with version 4.

The real problem that you are having is the following statement (I made it a bit shorter for readability):

```
C:/Alfresco/swftools/pdf2swf.exe, -T, 9, -s, poly2bitmap,subpixels=72, *C:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\your_source_file.pdf*, -o, *C:\Alfresco\tomcat\temp\Alfresco\generated_flash_preview.swf*
```

You might want to enter that in the command line, and see what happens. If you get errors, you might want to try a different version of pdf2swf.exe. If you don't get an error and things get nicely converted, you probably need to assign more memory to Alfresco's Java heap (parameter -Xmx), make sure that you have enough hard-drive space, and, naturally, that you have enough physical RAM memory.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the configuration that didn't meet my needs. My new configuration is on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

So first of all, thank you for all your answers !
It really helped me a lot.

Indeed, the problem came from `pdf2swf`. Alfresco's default configuration wasn't appropriate to big PDF files. The one that I have contains too many rich characters, so the default parameters' configuration of the "swf-transform.properties" :

```
swf.encoder.params=-s poly2bitmap,subpixels=72
```

was replaced by :

```
swf.encoder.params=-s zoom=72 -s ppmsubpixels=1 -s poly2bitmap=1 -s bitmapfonts=1
```

Now I can preview my big PDF file without any problem.

Thanks again for your help.